# Select a column without "losing" a dimension

Tags: python, tensorflow

Suppose I execute the following code

```
W = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,1), minval = 0, maxval = 1)
Z = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,1), minval = 0, maxval = 1)
X = tf.concat([W,Z],1)
```

The shape of `X[:,1]` would be `[100,]`. That is, `X[:,1].shape` would yield `[100,]`. If I want to select the second column of `X` and want the resulting array to have shape `[100,1]`, what should I do? I looked at `tf.slice` but I'm not sure if it' helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe just use `tf.newaxis` for your use case:

```py
import tensorflow as tf

W = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,1), minval = 0, maxval = 1)
Z = tf.random.uniform(shape = (100,1), minval = 0, maxval = 1)

X = tf.concat([W,Z],1)
print(X[:, 1, tf.newaxis].shape)
# (100, 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Y = X[:, 1]
Y.shape        
# which is [100]

Y = tf.reshape(Y, [100,1])
Y.shape
# which is [100, 1]
```

Comment: I know how to use `tf.reshape`. Does that affect the speed of my code?